# windows scheduled task is not triggered on restart if scheduled time is missed

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a task that is triggered at a scheduled time once every week and launches an executable. The "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" is also checked but still, if scheduled time is missed, the task doesn't run on restart. The next run time gets updated but there is nothing in the history or the last run time. I created this task using the Windows task scheduler API 2.0

For testing, I had manually updated the trigger time and then turned off my machine before the scheduled time.

Comment: Apparently this option does not include tasks that require the user to be logged on but whose scheduled times pass while the user is not logged on. Did you choose the option of "Run whether user is logged on or not"?

Comment: I found the issue. It was not running because I had "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" checked and my laptop was not connected to power supply.